# Get the number of rows to the next non-zero value in one column and sum in another column - Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window, window-functions

I have the following table in Pyspark:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  sku  | distribution center | leadtime | ind_abt |    date    | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  1234 |      New York       |    10    |    0    | 2022-01-01 |
|  1234 |      New York       |    10    |    0    | 2022-01-02 |
|  1234 |      New York       |    10    |    0    | 2022-01-03 |
|  1234 |      New York       |    10    |    1    | 2022-01-04 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

For each row, I'd like to calculate the distance to the next row with non-zero "ind_abt" value, and create a new column called leadtime_aux, which sums the leadtime value with that distance. This distance has to be calculated in the ("sku", "distribution_center") window and looking 15 lines below the current line.

For example, in the first row, the distance to the next row with column ind_abt != 0 is 3. So column leadtime_aux would be 13 (leadtime+3).
For the second row, the distance to the next non-zero row is 2, so leadtime_aux = 12.

The resulting table would look like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  sku  | distribution center | leadtime | ind_abt |    date    | leadtime_aux | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1234 |      New York       |    10    |    0    | 2022-01-01 |      13      |
|  1234 |      New York       |    10    |    0    | 2022-01-02 |      12      |
|  1234 |      New York       |    10    |    0    | 2022-01-03 |      11      |
|  1234 |      New York       |    10    |    1    | 2022-01-04 |      10      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You need a column to order by, do you have one?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to put here. There is a column "date" having a sequence of dates by sku and distribution_center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution here. I'll paste it here, it might be useful for someone in the future:

```
win = Window.partitionBy("sku", "distribution_center").orderBy("date")
win2 = Window.partitionBy("sku", "distribution_center").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(0, 15)
df = df.withColumn("rnum", row_number().over(win)) \
     .withColumn("delta", first(when(col("ind_abt") == 0, None).otherwise(col("rnum")), ignorenulls=True).over(win))\
     .withColumn("leadtime_aux", when(col("delta").isNull(), None).otherwise(abs(col("rnum")-col("delta")))+col("leadtime"))
```